# What is the SharePoint Crawled Property for Azure Active Directory "Country" property?

Tags: sharepoint-online, active-directory, pnp, sharepoint-search

I am trying to map the **"Country" field property from Azure Active Directory** User Profile to a **custom Managed Property in SharePoint** for search purposes.

What is the correct **"Crawled Property"** value to use for this field?

[image]

The closest "location" based value from Azure AD that I can successfully map is "Office Location" which is identified by `People:SPS-Location`

There is no **"country"** based property I can find under "Crawled Properties"

[image]

Comment: I’m checking how the things are going on about this issue. Whether the answer helps you?

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge SharePoint does not sync **Country or Region** Azure AD property to user profile by default.

As a workaround, you can create your custom user profile property and using PowerShell Script you can sync it to custom user profile properties. Once sync is finished then crawled property for it will be created automatically. if you want to sync the values on regular basis then you can configure [task scheduler](https://blog.netwrix.com/2018/07/03/how-to-automate-powershell-scripts-with-task-scheduler/) to run on specific interval or you can use other options like [Azure Function](https://dfinke.github.io/powershell,%20azure,%20functions/2017/05/01/Use-PowerShell-in-Azure-Functions-to-perform-a-scheduled-clean-up-task.html), etc.

**Below are the steps to create user profile properties**

1. Open SharePoint Admin Center
2. Go to User Profile

[image]
3. Click on Manage User Profile Properties

[image]

4. Click on "New Property"

[image]

5. Create user profile property with following configuration

[image]

**Links for PowerShell scripts to sync azure ad user property to user profile property**

1. https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2019/03/sharepoint-online-import-user-profile-property-from-azure-ad-using-powershell.html
2. https://www.tatvasoft.com/blog/how-to-sync-azure-ad-extension-attribute-with-user-profile-for-custom-property-in-office-365/